# Append text to an existing field that contains text

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to add text into a field that already contains text without clearing the existing text. Append the text essentially

The 'input text' keyword clears the field before each iteration so is not a viable solution

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use Get Text to retrieve what the field contains already, assign it to a variable, then use input text to add whatever you want. i.e

```
${original_text}=    Get Text    Input_Field_Locator
Input Text    Input_Field_Locator    ${original_text}+${append_text}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use javascript, by calling `Execute Javascript` keyword from `Selenium2Library` as the following:

`Execute Javascript  $("#inputfield").val($("#inputfield").val() + " some more text");`